# Excel 2007 hyperlinks to other workbooks not redirecting properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

Links within the workbook seem solid. Links to other workbooks on the network get replaced with C-drive home directory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Excel Options -> Advanced, scroll down to where it says

> At startup, open all files in:

and enter the network location on which you are working, e.g. O:\ or \\server\department\drive\